# Public Google Compute Engine Images

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've created a few images for some common stacks(JavaEE app, Node.js app, MySQL, etc.) that I'd like to share with the community.

These images are stored in a separate project. Seems the right way according to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/sharing-images-across-projects) is to grant `compute.imageUser` role to [`allUsers`](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#allusers). But it's not possible according to the same documentation.

I know there are [a few community projects that somehow bypassed that limitation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#os-compute-support). So my question is how did they do it? Is it only possible if Google will whitelist my project?

Seems AWS doesn't have such limitation and allows creating [Community AMIs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sharingamis-intro.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described on [this article](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#allusers), `allUsers` is a special identifier that represents anyone who is on the internet, with or without a Google account.

Based on documents that you posted, on both AWS and Google Cloud Platform launching and using an image is not possible by anyone (non-authenticated users) on the internet.

[The projects](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#os-compute-support) hosting and serving preconfigured public images belong to Google. These public images are available to users and service accounts that are members of GCP project(s) and, also are granted at least `roles/compute.imageUser` permission.

That being said, at this moment it is not possible to grant the `compute.imageUser` role to `allUsers` and `allAuthenticatedUsers` identifiers.
If you wish to share your custom images with all GCP users, I encourage you to [open a feature request](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/access-ui) for this on [Google public issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/).